# Wi-Fi starts only after Suspend (in Ubuntu) and Sleep or Hibernate (in Windows)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, multi-boot, sleep

So, I had dual boot - Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. The Wi-Fi worked well and good. Everything worked perfectly but then I had some problem with the hinge of my laptop and also the LCD so I had to give my laptop to a local repair shop for few hours. Then the hinge and the LCD problem was fixed but the Wi-Fi stopped working.

**In Windows** - I was unable to turn on the Wi-Fi, it was disabled, I couldn't enable the Wi-Fi and the enable option was greyed out. After troubleshooting it would say ***Wireless Capability is turned off.*** I pressed Fn + F12 but nothing would happen. But the Wi-Fi would start on its own automatically after few hours (sometimes 1 hour, sometimes 2 hours or more) without me doing anything. Then I replaced the HDD with one having Windows 7 installed. It worked properly over there with no problem at all. In win 8.1, I updated all the drivers, scanned for hardware changes (there was no hardware changes), I upgraded to Windows 10, nothing happened. But then I discovered, once I shutdown my PC and then boot it, the Wi-Fi was disabled but then i put it on Sleep or Hibernate it and then if i start it again, the Wi-Fi worked.

**In Ubuntu** - It said ***Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch.*** I opened up the backcover thinking some wired connection was done properly but everything was fine. I did the same, Fn + F12, sudo rfkill, but nothing happened. The wifi would not start, in both Windows and Ubuntu, the Ethernet cable worked just fine. But then also in Ubuntu I discovered, that after i boot to Ubuntu and then i put it on suspend and then again start ubuntu, the Wi-Fi would start working.

In both the cases the Wi-Fi doesn't work on boot but after Suspend/Sleep, it starts working. There was no such problem before I gave it for repairing. What is causing this issue?

Comment: The repair technician may have messed something up when fixing the hinge. Bring the laptop back to the shop and have them take a look at the problem.

Comment: @Larssend they did, and said it is a software problem. It sounds like a hardware problem? Because that is what i thought it is initially, but like i mentioned i attached a different HDD which had windows 7 installed but everything worked fine over there. Do you think they might have replaced the adapter ? And also they said, they repaired the hinge so they didn't have to touch any wires related to Wireless.